# Cannot create new VM from powercli

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli

I'm using PowerCLI 6.0 to create a new virtual machine from another virtual machine. I'm using this cmdlet:

```
New-VM -Name MyName -VM $sourceVM -Datastore $myDataStore -VMHost (Get-VMHost)
```

But it returns following exception:

> New-VM The operation for the entity "xxx" failed with the following message: "The operation is not supported on the object."

The source VM is powered off. Version of vSphere is 5.5.

I tried to google this error but without any success.

Now, I have no idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-vmhost by itself will return all hosts and not specify one host to use, which is what this command expects.

If you know a host you wish to build on you could use the below script:

```
New-VM -Name MyName -VM $sourceVM -Datastore $myDataStore -VMHost $(Get-VMHost "specify host name")
```

Otherwise you could build an array and select a vmhost from that array by using the below

```
# This command builds an array of all you host names into the variable $vmh

$vmh = get-vmhost 

# This command selects random host from this array assigning it to the $vmhost variable

$vmhost = Get-random -inputobject $vmh

# Now build your VM command with the randomly selected host 

New-VM -Name MyName -VM $sourceVM -Datastore $myDataStore -VMHost $vmhost
```

Make sure you are defining a datastore in a similar fashion as well for your $mydatastore variable

Just making a variable built off get-datastore will not work you have to narrow it down to a single store for the operation New-VM to work

```
$mds = get-datastore

$mydatastore = Get-random -InputObject $mds
```

Also make sure your $sourceVM is being defined correctly as well. if more than one object is in this variable it will not work. Make sure $sourceVM equals a single VM name.

As you can see below, when I run the command without clearly identifying it in the variable it gives me nearly the same error (Please note my errors will look a bit different because I use PowerGUI to generate and build my scripts). The highlighted text is the command I ran which looks like yours. The text in red in the red box at the bottom is the error. B y defining your host through random selection or by name should make the command work.

[PowerGUI Image VM Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpyVm.png)

I also replied to your VMWare Community Forum post as well.

Comment: Ok, your answer will help almost people. But in my case the problem was a little bit different. I was connected directly to VMHost under the admin account but the admin hadn't rights to clone existing VMs. I had to connect to vCenter as the admin and run your script.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you were able to figure it out. I had also noted on VMWare Forums some info about whether you were connecting to vcenter or not. One article I linked said that certain functions in PowerCLI will only work if script is being run against the vcenter server itself and not through the host.  https://communities.vmware.com/thread/478345

Answer (score 1):

VMHOST requires you to pass a parameter.
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI55/html/Get-VMHost.html

First you need to connect to ESXI Server using 'connect-viserver' and then perform the creation of new VM.

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to ESXI Server. There is no change when I use Get-VMHost with a parameter.

Comment: What is Get-VMHost Return you?